# How I get y-axis bold & new times roman font when using latex as 'TickLabelInterpreter' in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, fonts, latex

I am trying to use latex as TickLabelInterprete in Matlab. I want to bold both the x-axis (where I use the x-ticklabel along with latex syntax) and y-axis (nothing used, just normal text). At the same time, I want to set the font of all the texts on the figure to be Times New Roman.

I am attaching my code as follows. It appears to be strange for me, when I do not set the TickLabelInterprete to be latex, everything is fine, I can bold the y-axis easily (both y-label and the number on the y-axis). But when TickLabelInterprete = 'latex', the number on the y-axis will automatically turn back to normal font. Any suggestions?

```
close all;
data = [1,1,1,1;2,2,2,2;3,3,3,3;4,4,4,4];
bar(data)
hold on
grid on
xticks([1 2 3 4])
xtickangle(0)

ax = gca;
ax.TickLabelInterpreter = 'latex';

xTicklabels = {'\textbf{label 1} \boldmath$E_1$', ...
    '\textbf{label 2} \boldmath$E_2$', ...
    '\textbf{label 3} \boldmath$E_3$', ...
    '\textbf{label 4} \boldmath$E_4$'};

set(gca,'XTickLabel',xTicklabels);

xlabel("Different algorithms");
ylabel("Result of schemes");

lgd = legend("1",...
    "2",...
    "3",...
    "4",...
    'Location',"northwest");
lgd.FontWeight = "bold";

h = gca;
h.XAxis.FontWeight = 'bold';
h.XAxis.LineWidth = 1;
h.YAxis.FontWeight = 'bold';
h.YAxis.LineWidth = 1;
set(gca,'fontname','times');


hold off;
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to set `h.YAxis.TickLabelFormat` to **bold** as well. For the case of `xTicklabels`, you've done it manually; you could do the same for the `yTicklabels`, but the faster way here is to set the `TickLabelFormat` since the ticks are already normal numbers and need no customization.

```
close all;
data = [1 1 1 1; 2 2 2 2; 3 3 3 3; 4 4 4 4];
bar(data)
grid on
xticks([1 2 3 4])
xtickangle(0)

ax = gca;
ax.TickLabelInterpreter = 'latex';

xTicklabels = {'\textbf{label 1} \boldmath$E_1$', ...
    '\textbf{label 2} \boldmath$E_2$', ...
    '\textbf{label 3} \boldmath$E_3$', ...
    '\textbf{label 4} \boldmath$E_4$'};

set(gca,'XTickLabel',xTicklabels);

xlabel("Different algorithms");
ylabel("Result of schemes");

lgd = legend("1", "2", "3", "4", 'Location', "northwest");
lgd.FontWeight = "bold";

h = gca;
h.XAxis.FontWeight = 'bold';
h.XAxis.LineWidth = 1;
h.YAxis.FontWeight = 'bold';
h.YAxis.LineWidth = 1;
set(gca,'fontname','times');
h.YAxis.TickLabelFormat = '\\textbf{%g}';   % <---- ADD THIS LINE
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ammar! Can I also set the font of these numbers on the y-axis to be times new roman?